# Flex: looking for Su-Sa Cal control

Tags: apache-flex, calendar, controls

Ive been tasked with doing some scheduling work for our dept. One issue is the use of shared spaces (conference rooms, etc). To schedule such spots Im hoping to find a flex control that displays SuMTWThFSa with hours of the day onto which I can drag blocks of time.

There are several commercial calendars (Ilog being one) that let one schedule using blocks of time over a calendar but they are pinned to actual dates. I want something that is just a week at a glance.

Does such a beast exist?

Comment: The Flextras Calendar has a "Week view"; but you'd have to write your own day renderer to implement the "Gantt Chart" style "Time Grid" that lets you click and drag Calendar objects to different spots.  If you just want a week view with no consideration for dates, just create a component for the 'day' and lay out 7 of them in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.  You can look a premade 3rd party ones or maybe you'll be lucky to find someone posting the code for their components.  It doesn't seems to be that hard to do, but since everyone has different requirements, it would be very hard to make a component that could be reused efficiently.

Comment: I guess I'll probably end up rolling my own. Oh well.